# join 3 tables with sort

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables I'd like to put together. A video table with all the users videos, an image table with all the users images and a cameras table. I want to list all images and videos and sort them

prefix_videos table with `(videoid, userid, cameraid, videosize, datetime, deleted, videolength, videoname)`

prefix_images table with `(imageid, userid, cameraid, imagesize, datetime, deleted, imagename)`

prefix_cameras table with `(userid, cameraid, ...)`

Previously I only had the videos table so this query gave me what I needed:

```
SELECT prefix_videos.videoid, prefix_videos.videoname, prefix_videos.videosize, 
prefix_videos.videodatetime, prefix_videos.videolength, prefix_cameras.cameraname FROM 
prefix_videos INNER JOIN prefix_cameras USING (userid,cameraid) WHERE 
prefix_videos.deleted IS NULL AND prefix_videos.userid=xxx ORDER BY 
prefix_videos.datetime DESC
```

But now I'm adding an image table. So what I want is to build a table with:

`imageid/videoid, cameraid, imagesize/videosize, datetime (either from image or video table), videoname/imagename`

Because I'm now combining the image and video table to give one result I'm not sure another INNER JOIN makes sense here?

The other important part here is the check for NULL for deleted entries and the ability to ORDER these by the date whether it comes from images or videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create the two selects separately for video and image, and then bring them together with a union. The messy part is that you'd have to sort after afaik

```
select * from(
SELECT prefix_videos.videoid, prefix_videos.videoname, prefix_videos.videosize, 
    prefix_videos.videodatetime, prefix_videos.videolength, prefix_cameras.cameraname FROM 
    prefix_videos INNER JOIN prefix_cameras USING (userid,cameraid) WHERE 
    prefix_videos.deleted IS NULL AND prefix_videos.userid=xxx ORDER BY 
    prefix_videos.datetime DESC
    union
    SELECT prefix_images.imageid, prefix_images.imagename, prefix_images.imagesize, 
    prefix_images.imagesdatetime, prefix_images.videolength, prefix_cameras.cameraname FROM 
    prefix_images INNER JOIN prefix_cameras USING (userid,cameraid) WHERE 
    prefix_images.deleted IS NULL AND prefix_images.userid=xxx ORDER BY 
    prefix_images.datetime DESC
)a order by 'mycolumn'
```

or

```
select imageid/videoid, cameraid, imagesize/videosize, datetime (either from image or video table), videoname/imagename

from 
(select imageid as 'imageid/videoid', cameraid ,imagesize as 'imagesize/videosize', datetime, imagename as 'videoname/imagename' from prefix_images where ...
union 
select videoid as 'imageid/videoid', cameraid ,videosize as 'imagesize/videosize', datetime, videoname as 'videoname/imagename' from prefix_videos where ...
)as temptable
inner join whatever_your_table on temptable.selected_column=whatever_your_table .equivalent_column
order by 'mycolumn'
```

Comment: This is not working for me, I think because the columns are not the same. So I think this breaks UNION's rules. Still trying to figure it out...

Comment: you can use cast() to convert different columns to different types.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, you can JOIN upon JOIN upon JOIN. The syntax typically looks like

```
select [stuff] from [tableA]
 join [tableB]
 on [tableA.column] = [tableB.column]
 join [tableC]
 on [tableAorTableB.column] = [tableC.column]
 where [conditions]
```

and so on. I'm oversimplifying but you get the idea.

Comment: Ah, the real question is -should- I do a three-way JOIN, not -can- I. AdrianBR has a better answer here.